# Which Desktop Linux version can run decently on For P4 & 750MB Ram

Tags: linux, ubuntu, desktop, desktop-environment

I just installed Ubunta 13.10 on an old P4 with 750MB Ram, but the system is running too slow to be used for anything. I had XP running on it and worked fast enough to use, but I decided I wanted to try Linux because I read it would run faster on it.

1)Ubunta did not appear to reformat the harddrive, I don't know if that should have been done or not, but it appeared to install right over XP. Is there some method of installation, other than booting the ISO and following the steps to install that would make it run faster?

2)Is there a better desktop version of Linux would run faster on a P4 with 750MB of RAM.

Comment: You could try [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net).  It's based on [LXDE](http://lxde.org/lxde)

Comment: Similar question: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14757/which-gnu-linux-distribution-for-a-12-year-old-system

Comment: install ubuntu on the hardrive with format and remove XP, that's normal it's slow if you install over windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an old system, so I would avoid anything with a fancy window manager. You could try running Xubuntu, since it has a light-weight window manager. I would advise you to steer clear of older Linux versions because they might not be supported anymore (especially security patches).

When installing Ubuntu/Xubuntu, let it use the entire drive. It will repartition the drive and remove all existing content.